# IE <select>, how to make the displayed width the smallest possible for the current options

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select, width

I've written a function which takes a `<select>` ID, and replaces all the options with new ones (using jQuery's `html()`). However, on IE the width of the dropdown remains the original one which has a size way bigger than what I need to display, because is based on the original `<option>`'s that had long strings captions.

Is there a way to force the `<select>` to recalculate it's width?

I am using IE 8.

Comment: You could try to reattach it to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the pragmatic solution would be to replace the whole `<select>` element. This way, the newly inserted one will have the correct width for its `<option>` elements (disregarding any other styling that may be applied).

The thing to bear in mind if replacing the whole select is that any references to the replaced element will need to cleaned up prior to removing it from the DOM (to avoid any potential memory leaks) and event handlers attached to the newly inserted element.

Comment: Indeed, is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set its width through css.
In your case I would approach it using this method:

If you are using em's or ex's as font size units, then since it is a value based on height, you can assume using a certain ratio that it is almost near the equivalent of a character's width. Based on that, you can actually calculate how wide your select element would be by:

1st: get the number of characters of the smallest string from the select options.
2nd: multiply that by the em value.
3rd: set this value as the select's width.

using jquery that would be achieved through:

```
var em = 1em; //assign here a value, that corresponds to your layout's font size
var shortest = 6500;
$('mySelect').each(function(i, selected){
   temp = $(selected).text().length();
   shortest = (temp < shortest) ? temp : shortest;
});
$('mySelect').css('width',(shortest*em + 1) + 'em'); //add 1em for the scrollbar
```